# listview dynamic message using Flags

Tags: android

i am working on a chat application. I am able to send and receive message normally. But when i try to integrate bubble message, i need guidance. i have 2 layouts

1. left layout(Display sent message by me,  2. right layout() display received messages. I am able to display message i am sending in bubble message. I am not able to display the received message. How should i go ahead.

sample code is given below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = null;
            String jid = null;
            String even_color, odd_color;
            SharedPreferences prefList = getSharedPreferences("PrefsFile",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            even_color = prefList.getString("even_bubble_color", "pink");
            odd_color = prefList.getString("odd_bubble_color", "green");

            int even_color_id = getResources().getIdentifier(even_color,
                    "drawable", "com.teks.chilltwit"), odd_color_id =     getResources()
                    .getIdentifier(odd_color, "drawable",     "com.teks.chilltwit");

            //ImageView even_view, odd_view;
        // System.out.println("Timeline: Position: "+position+", Length:     "+data.length);
        // if(position!=data.length-1){

             if (jid != null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd,     parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView)     row.findViewById(R.id.text);
                textLabel.setText(datav);
            }

            else {
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_even,     parent,
                        false);
                TextView textLabel = (TextView)     row.findViewById(R.id.text);
                textLabel.setText("" + messages);
        }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

In the above code, i need to display left layout if i send the message and else i need to display right layout if i receive message. Please guide me in this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem here is that the jid is always not null?

Comment: s. u r right. if null i must receive received message. if not null i need to display message i sent.. How can i do that.

Comment: The problem is definitely not in this piece of code, because u set the jid to be null and never assign anything to it...